# Use tensor product to show that $ \mathscr{T}^n=\sum_{j \geq 1} \lambda_j^n e_j \otimes e_j $?

Tags: functional-analysis

I learned tensor product before. The definition is Definition 3.4.6 Let $x_1, x_2$ be elements of Hilbert spaces $\mathbb{H}_1$ and $\mathbb{H}_2$, respectively. The tensor product operator $\left(x_1 \otimes_1 x_2\right): \mathbb{H}_1 \mapsto \mathbb{H}_2$ is defined by

$$
\left(x_1 \otimes_1 x_2\right) y=\left\langle x_1, y\right\rangle_1 x_2
$$

for $y \in \mathbb{H}_1$. If $\mathbb{H}_1=\mathbb{H}_2$ we use $\otimes$ in lieu of $\otimes_1$.

Suppose that $\mathbb{H}_i=\mathbb{R}^{p_i}, i=1,2$ for some finite positive integers $p_2, p_1$. Then,

$$
x_1 \otimes_1 x_2=x_2 x_1^T
$$

for $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^{p_i}, i=1,2$ : namely, $x_1 \otimes_1 x_2$ is the vector outer product of $x_2$ and $x_1$.

Please use my definition to prove that:

The representation of a self-adjoint compact operator $\mathcal{T}$: $$\mathcal{T} = \sum_{j \geq 1} \lambda_j e_j \otimes e_j$$ satisfies

$$
\mathscr{T}^n=\sum_{j \geq 1} \lambda_j^n e_j \otimes e_j
$$

for any positive integer $n$ : namely, $\left(\lambda_j^n, e_j\right), j \geq 1$, are the eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs of $\mathscr{T}^n$.

I know we can use math induction to show. But I am not good at using tensor product. I try to do:

Assume that the equation holds for some positive integer $n$, i.e.,
$$\mathcal{T}^n = \sum_{j \geq 1} \lambda_j^n e_j \otimes e_j$$

We need to show that it also holds for $n+1$.

$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{T}^{n+1} &= \mathcal{T}^n \mathcal{T} \\
&= \left(\sum_{j \geq 1} \lambda_j^n e_j \otimes e_j\right) \left(\sum_{k \geq 1} \lambda_k e_k \otimes e_k\right) \\
&= \sum_{j \geq 1} \sum_{k \geq 1} \lambda_j^n \lambda_k (e_j \otimes e_j)(e_k \otimes e_k)
\end{aligned}$$

I don't know how to do next.

Comment: Notice how, if I'm not mistaken, $(e_j\otimes e_j)(e_k\otimes e_k)=0$ if $j\neq k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definitions imply :
$$
(e_j \otimes e_j)(e_k \otimes e_k) = e_je_j^Te_ke_k^T = e_j \langle e_j,e_k \rangle e_k^T = \delta_{jk} (e_j \otimes e_k),
$$
where we assumed that the basis of the Hilbert space is orthonormal in order to write $\langle e_j,e_k \rangle = \delta_{jk}$, with $\delta_{jk}$ the Kronecker delta. In consequence, one has :
$$
\sum_{j\geq1}\sum_{k\geq1} \lambda_j^n\lambda_k (e_j \otimes e_j)(e_k \otimes e_k) = \sum_{j\geq1}\sum_{k\geq1} \lambda_j^n\lambda_k \delta_{jk} (e_j \otimes e_k) = \sum_{j\geq1} \lambda_j^{n+1} (e_j \otimes e_j) = \mathcal{T}^{n+1}
$$